# better approach to creat an xml in java

Tags: java, xml

I am creating xml through dom parser as shown below in a method Please advise is there any other better approach to achieve the same in java as dom parser is considered to be loading the memory that why i was looking for better approach

```
String xmlString = null ;  
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
            SimpleDateFormat dateformatyyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");



            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("abcmail");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);



            Element invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage = doc.createElement("invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage");
            rootElement.appendChild(invoiceReferenceNotificationMessage);


            Element ceReference = doc.createElement("ceReference");
            ceReference.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(irm.getceReference()));
            ceReferenceNotificationMessage.appendChild(ceReference);


            Element RBSReference = doc.createElement("ABSReference");
            ABSReference.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(irm.getABSReference()));
            ceReferenceNotificationMessage.appendChild(ABSReference);


            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

            transformer.transform(source, result);
            writer.flush();
            xmlString = writer.toString();

            return xmlString;

          } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
          } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
          }
        return xmlString;

    }
```

Comment: I'd just use this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/writingDom.html It is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Side note on code quality: I hope this is just example code; but besides worrying on rumtime performance; please consider carefully **how** to write your code. You should not have a single block that is responsible for creating a DomBuilder; the root element, and all the following elements. Instead, you should be having many small methods. What does good runtime performance help, when your code is written in a way that makes it **hard** to maintain and modify in the future?

Comment: @Jägermeister can you please update my code to show how it can be better organised that will help me to grasp more

Comment: I have an idea that requires less work on my end ;-) I write down this link ( https://cleansourcecode.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/clean-code.pdf ), you download the PDF and study it. I guarantee you: if you are serious about programming, you will not regret it (although we are talking a few hundred pages in the end)

Answer (score 1):

The better way is using JAXB.

You can see an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

Comment: Thanks I am using jdk 1.5 please

Comment: check if this can help u: https://java.net/projects/jaxb/lists/users/archive/2012-09/message/22